# How to animate single character in js or using jquery on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, blast.js

I can animate the whole word or if i use any other selector but with blast as the class i cannot animate single character.

```
//used blast.js to seperate each character
   $("h1").blast({ delimiter: "character" }); 

//on hover function to animate each character on hover and used bounce animation using animate.css from github, https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/
    $(".blast").hover(
        function()
    {
       ` $(this).addClass("animated bounce");`

    },
        function()
    {
    `$(this).removeClass("animated bounce");`
        });
```

*

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `.blast` elements don't exist when the document is prepared, so you have to bind the event handler to them using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Note that in this particular case, using the "unhover" callback (or `mouseleave`) events will cause the elements to snap back down after they bounce off the mouse, or the mouse moves. This could lead to potentially undesirable results.

I've modified it to remove the class after the animation has run (1 second in `bounce`'s case)

One more thing to note is that with most animations like this, they won't work on `inline` elements (e.g. `<span>`'s), so you have to set them to `inline-block`.

Have a look at this snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Blast the `<h1>` element
  $('h1').blast({ delimiter: 'character' });
  
  // `Rebind the `mouseenter` event handler to the new `.blast` elements
  $('h1').on('mouseenter', '.blast', function(){

    // Store the targeted `.blast` element as an instanced variable
    var $target = $(this);

    // Add the animation classes to it
    $target.addClass('animated bounce');

    // Run the `removeClass` function on our instanced variable after
    // 1 sec (animation length of `.bounce`)
    setTimeout(function(){
      $target.removeClass('animated bounce');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
/* span.blast is inline by default, so animations won't 
   work unless we make it a block or inline-block element */
.blast {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blast-text@2.0.0/jquery.blast.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a headline</h1>
```

Comment: It would be better to bind to the `h1` though instead of going all the way up to the `document`.

Answer (score -2):

Use Jquery Simple script (NO LIBERY SOME PLUGINS)!!
And use CSS3 animations:
https://animate.style/

```
<h2 class="animate_text" data-animate="animate__rubberBand" data-hide-animate="900"> Front End Developer</h2>
        
$(".animate_letter_hover").each(function() {
    
      var
      $this              = $(this),
          $dataAnimate   = $(this).data("animate"),
          $dataHideAnimate = $(this).data("hide-animate");
    
      $this.html(function(index, html) {
        return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
      });
    
      $(".animate_letter_hover > span").on("mouseenter click touchstart", function() {
    
        var
        $this            = $(this);
    
        $this.addClass($this.parent().data("animate") + " animate__animated ");
    
        setTimeout(function() {
    
          $this.removeClass();
    
        }, $dataHideAnimate);
    
      });
    
    });
```

LOOK EXAMPLE AWESOME
https://jsfiddle.net/zdimaz/14rqbo8k/109/